# Combine to two tables within a single query to order data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables `word_term_relationships` and `word_posts`

What I'm doing is using a `while` loop in order to fetch a certain record from the `word_term_relationships` table where a certain value is true.

```
$query = "SELECT object_id 
          FROM `word_term_relationships` 
          WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = '54'";
```

I then use another query within the loop to use the data that was retrieved from the previous query in order to fetch data from the other table `word_posts`

```
$query2 = "SELECT post_title, post_date, post_date_gmt, guid 
           FROM `word_posts` 
           WHERE `ID` = '$post_id'";
```

This I can do and works fine.

The only issue is that I then need to order the results by date and time, I can do this without the `while` loop and using the `ORDER BY` function and the `word_posts` table.

However, I've tried to link the tables within the query like this (below) in order to order the data. But obviously it isn't correct - I just can't pinpoint within the query what is wrong.

```
$query = "SELECT word_term_relationships.object_id 
          FROM word_term_relationships 
          WHERE word_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = '54' 
          ORDER BY word_posts.post_date ASC";
```

I know the above query is missing something, I was thinking a second `where` after the `ORDER BY word_posts.post_date ASC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `INNER JOIN` will solve your problem. Try this,

```
SELECT a.post_title, 
       a.post_date, 
       a.post_date_gmt, 
       a.guid 
FROM   word_posts a 
       INNER JOIN word_term_relationships b
           ON a.ID = b.object_id
WHERE  b.term_taxonomy_id= '54'
ORDER BY a.post_date ASC
```

Comment: need to have order by a.post_date

Comment: Then add "order by a.post_date" to the end of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT post_title
               , post_date
               , post_date_gmt
               , guid
          FROM word_posts a INNER JOIN word_term_relationships b on a.ID = b.object_id
          WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '54'
          ORDER BY a.post_date ASC";
```